# Images matching using bf.match and drawing using cv2.drawMatches Python

Tags: python, image-classification, matplotlib

I have successfully matched 2 images using bf.Match and drawn matches as well. Now, I am trying to match multiple images from 2 different directories.

For this, I am using 2 different array to store images from 2 different directories. Everything seems to be working fine and printing the array actually shows the points as well when printed.

However, cv2.drawMatches throws an error TypeError: queryDescriptors is not a numerical tuple when looping it. I am using while loop to loop the cv2.drawMatches function and iterate the stored array values.

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Below is my code that I have so far developed to achieve this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
path = 'path_to_directory_1'
files = []
descriptors_1 = []
keypoints_1 = []
keypoints_2 = []
descriptors_2 = []
img1 = []
img2 = []

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.PNG' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    imgtest1 = cv2.imread(f)
    imgraw1 = cv2.cvtColor(imgtest1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img1.append(imgraw1)
    descriptors_1.append(sift.detectAndCompute(imgraw1,None))
    keypoints_1.append(sift.detectAndCompute(imgraw1,None))

path = 'path_to_directory_2'
files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.PNG' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    imgtest2 = cv2.imread(f)
    imgraw2 = cv2.cvtColor(imgtest2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img2.append(imgraw2)
    descriptors_2.append(sift.detectAndCompute(imgraw2,None))
    keypoints_2.append(sift.detectAndCompute(imgraw2,None))

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L1, crossCheck=True)
size = len(descriptors_1)
count = 0
while (count <= size):
  print(descriptors_1[count])
  count = count + 1
  matches = bf.match(descriptors_1[count], descriptors_2[count])
  matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
  img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1[count], keypoints_1[count], img2[count], keypoints_2[count], matches[:50], img2[count], flags=2)
  plt.imshow(img3)
  plt.show()
```